# Error when trying to edit/delete a copy of the seatle.master master page. "Server error. This file may not be moved,deleted,renamed or otherwise "

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, development, master-page

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection inside SharePoint 2013. and using sharepoint designer i copy the seatle.master and i past it so i get a new master page named `seattle_copy(1).master`, but if i try to edit or delete this master page i will get the following error

> "Server error. This file may not be moved,deleted,renamed or otherwise
>   edited"

as shown in the following pic:-

[image]

Comment: Copying the seattle.html and renaming it does not create a hyperlink prompt for me. It just renames it and creates a new .master file. and that new.master file does not have similar format to the one you see in the original seattle.master. this is very confusing ive been trying to solve this a week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't delete the copy because it is associated to the Seattle.html file.

What you have to do is create a copy of the Seattle.html file to. This will create a copy of the html file (Seattle_copy(1).html) that you need to rename to anything you want, maybe "delete" as an example. Doing this will give you a dialog that asks if you would like to update the hyperlinks. Select Yes.

This will rename the html file and create a new master page with the same name (delete.html & delete.master), and now you should be able to delete the first copy of Seattle.master that you created. To get rid of the extra html file and master page, delete the html file and the related master page should be deleted as well.

The steps is also covered here. [Issue with creating a copy of Seattle master page - Mikael Svensson](http://techmikael.blogspot.se/2013/02/issue-with-creating-copy-of.html)